# Javascript Hoisting

Tags: javascript

Quite an interesting thing was discovered by me as a JS learner, consider the following code.

```
  this.init = function (e) {
        var container = e.container;

        // slider
        var slider = $("#div1").slider({ orientation: "horizontal", step: 1,
            slide: function () {

                console.log(e.container); // not null
                console.log(container); // null
            }
        });
   };
```

here's how it's called:

```
lib.init({ container: $("#container") });
```

I know that I can use `on("slide", {container: container}, function(event, args){...}))` to bind slide event and pass external data into it. But - could anyone explain why values returned by two console.log are different? Also I wonder if the technique is a technically sound replacement for `on` approach?

Comment: ^^^--- Any chance on a slimmed down fiddle of your actual code that reproduces this ?

Comment: Can you give us an live example as [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: damn @Glutamat was faster :-*

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I am amazed that you are getting a `null` for `container`. Would actually want to see your logs if you can post

Secondly, here's an explanation of why this won't work, but **not** of why you get a `null`:

This has nothing to do with hoisting

you are executing the `init` function with `lib.init({ container: $("#container") });`

At that time attached function `this.init = function (e) { ...` gets executed with some value of `e`, may be an `Event`, so `e` is defined and the variable `container` gets a value

Whereas, in the following code on 5th line,

```
var slider = $("#div1").slider( ... // u are calling slider
```

the `slider` function is being **called** with options, and one of the options is:

```
slide: function () { // anonymous and will execute later
    console.log(e.container); // not null
    console.log(container); // null
}
```

1. most important, you are in the scope of `slider` function of your library, as it is being executed
2. here, the function you are attaching to `slide: ...` has not been executed yet. It will, when `slide` event happens
3. when that happens, the present value of `container` will be used

If you are getting a `null`, something definitely is resetting `container`, as in the fiddle **[here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/WJ2s8/)** by yckart its not null and is same as `e.container`

Comment: The only true sentences are the first three; it has nothing to do with hoisting. However, the value of `e` within that explicit call is certain, and the points #1 and #3 are completely wrong.

Comment: @Bergi, I kind of know that it is **not right**. Haven't tested the code and wrote answer **believing** that the OP actually got those logs. Thanks. Also, how is point #1 wrong?

Comment: The scope of a javascript function is determined by the function definition, not by its call.

Comment: But I said "you are in the scope of slider function **of your library**". Anyways, I agree that point #3 and #4 wrong. deleting

Comment: OK, maybe I misunderstood that; I only can see the `slide` function inside the scope of the `init` function (named by the properties they are assigned to).

Comment: @bergi, kindly check if my new #3 is correct. thanks :). I agree my answer is not on track with OP, but don't want to delete it either :)

Comment: Yes, #3 is correct. Yet I can't see any code which would change the value of the `container` variable...

Answer (score 2):

Can't see a difference... For me are both `logs` equal: http://fiddle.jshell.net/WJ2s8/